# Rally collection viewing permissions

Tags: web-services, permissions, rally

I am running into a problem where I am using the WSAPI to add a project to a person's TeamMemberships collection. When I add a project to this collection I get a 'you lack permissions to view Project XXXXXXXXXX' but I am NOT even trying to view that project.

I also get that same error when i put the _ref of that project in the URL bar, so i definitely lack permissions to view this project.

My question is: do i need viewer access to all items in a collection to add an item to that collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, editor access to all items in the collection is needed to update a collection. Viewer access is not enough.

In a specific case of a collection update when TeamMemberships collection is modified, editor access is not enough because this action requires administrative privileges, minimally Project Admin rights.
Since a Workspace Admin has access to all projects in the workspace, we don't need to consider that scenario.

Here are the details. Let's start with a more general collection update, e.g. defects collection on defect suite.

Let's say there are two sibling projects Child1 and Child2.
Some user A has editor rights to Child1, and no access to Child2. 
Assuming that there is:

a defect suite /defectsuite/444 with an empty defects collection in Child1,

two defects /defect/111 and /defect/222 in Child1,

a defect /defect/333 in Child2

User A successfully adds /defect/111 to the defect suite using this curl command:

```
curl --header "zsessionid:_abc123" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d"{\"CollectionItems\":[{\"_ref\":\"/defect/1111\"}]}" https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defectsuite/444/defects/add
```

Next, some other user B who has editor rights to both projects Child1 and Child2 adds /defect/333 to /defectsuite/444. Now the defects collection on this defect suite consists of two defects, one of which exists outside of User A's access.

Next, User A tries to add /defect/222 (which exists in Child1 project to which Editor A has full access) using a curl command similar to the one above, and gets an error:

**"Could not add artifact to collection", "Could not read: Not authorized to read object Defect 333"**

If at this point User A is given Viewer access to Child2 project and tries again the error will be different:

**"Could not add artifact to collection", "Could not set value for Defects: Not authorized to update:DefectSuite 444"**

To update the collection that contains defects from two projects User A needs to be an editor in both. Upgrading this user's rights to Editor level in Child2 project allows this action to complete successfully.

Now let's consider two scenarios in a TeamMemberships update.

1. Editor: Attempt by a user with editor rights to all projects in a workspace to update TeamMemberships collection for another user, /user/777 results in error:

**"Could not add artifact to collection", "Could not set value for Team Memberships: Not authorized to update:User 777"**

2. Project Admin: This is a minimal level of permissions that may work. Here is a scenario:
   User A has project admin rights to /project/111 and /project/222 and their child projects, and no access to /project/333 and its child projects in the same workspace.

Note that at this point the /user/777 whose teammemberships User A tries to update has no membership in any projects in this workspace. This command successfully updates TeamMembership for /user/777

```
curl --header "zsessionid:_abc123" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d"{\"CollectionItems\":[{\"_ref\":\"/project/111\"}]}" https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user/777/teammemberships/add
```

The returned JSON includes:

```
"TeamMembers": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/111/TeamMembers"
```

Next some other User B updates the teammembership collection of /user/777 with  /project/333 to which User A has no access.

Next, User A tries to update update teammembership collection of /user/777 with /project/222 where User A is a project editor.

This results in error:

**"Could not add artifact to collection", "Could not read: Not authorized to read object Project 333"**

At this point if User A is given Viewer or even Editor rights to /project/333 the same curl command will fail with this error:

**"Could not add artifact to collection", "Could not set value for Team Memberships: Not authorized to update:User 777"**

Project editor rights for /project/111, /project/222 and /project/333 will be needed in this case.

Comment: Thanks, that explains the issue. I had workspace admin priveledges, but the user was a teammember of a project in the workspace that was 'Closed'. and apparently workspace admins cannot view closed projects. so your explanation makes sense.